# Tor browser health report - not able to view it and clicking on it doesn't do anything

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux

I'm new to Tor and am on linux. I am trying to figure out what Tor browser health report is about. But I am unable to access it. By unable to access it, I mean the webpage is blank. Clicking on Edit > Preference > Advanced > Data Choices > Click on Tor browser health report does nothing. If I close Tor Browser Preferences, the checkbox becomes empty again.

Have no idea what's going on here. Is Tor browser health report not available anymore or anything else. Maybe noscript is denying it, although I have white listed about:healthreport .

Looking forward to know what is going on.